# ModPagespeedFileCachePath must not be empty

Tags: apache2, mod-pagespeed

I'm running Debian and [installed **mod_pagespeed**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/download) some weeks ago. Today there was a new version available when running apt-get update and upgrade. So I simply accepted it and ran it.

After manually restarted my Apache, it says in the error.log:

```
[...] [error] [mod_pagespeed 1.3.25.4-2941 @12950] mod_pagespeed is enabled. ModPagespeedFileCachePath must not be empty: defn_name=(null) defn_line_number=0 server_hostname=mydomain.com port=0
Configuration Failed
```

I deleted all stuff inside of `/var/cache/mod_pagespeed` (Which is the value of `ModPagespeedFileCachePath`) but it does not help.

Also uninstalling and reinstalling mod_pagespeed does not help.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this error means that you don't have the `ModPagespeedFileCachePath` directive set in one of your VHosts (or that you tried to set it to the empty string).

I've seen this come up in configurations like:

```
ModPagespeed off
ModPagespeedFileCachePath /var/cache/mod_pagespeed
...

<VirtualHost *:*>
  ServerName foo.example.com
  ModPagespeed on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I believe that in these cases you will need to add relevant ModPagespeed configuration into each `VirtualHost` you turn `ModPagespeed on` in. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ServerName foo.example.com
  ModPagespeed on
  ModPagespeedFileCachePath /var/cache/mod_pagespeed
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

It's also possible that [`ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#virtual-hosts) would solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising.

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution to get my server back online was to remove mod_pagespeed by:

```
dpkg -r mod-pagespeed-stable
```